Do U.S. universities allow online teachers to teach from a foreign countries?
I have experience teaching at a university (both face-to-face and online), and would like do so from another country.
Can a U.S citizen who is fully qualified to work in the U.S and to teach at a U.S. university do so from a foreign country? If the answer varies by university, does anyone know of specific universities that allow such an arrangement?

What has your own research on this topic revealed so far?

US universities are no different than any other employer in that regard. Having a foreign employee requires registering in the foreign jurisdiction and complying with the foreign labor and tax laws. Most employers who don't already have a local office in that jurisdictions will probably not want to deal with the complexity for a single employee. Universities don't generally branch out globally (with maybe some very specific and unique examples to the contrary).

The other answer suggests that some employers may want to "turn a blind eye" to their labor law violations, but these are usually the employers you don't want to work for. When they don't pay you, when they fire you, when you need to claim disability, workers' compensation, unemployment, or social security, you'll discover that you were never legally employed and have no recourse. Labor laws are there for a reason, and while there are employers who'd gladly ignore them if you let them, it is for your detriment.

Some years ago, I posed a similar question to a New York based university where I was teaching an online class as an adjunct. This was long before COVID lockdown rendered remote instruction less novel. My question was, would they mind if I did some of the work from Canada. Their official response was that:
They didn't care, but I'm responsible to make sure that Canada doesn't care
I'm responsible to make sure I have adequate internet access
I'm doing work in New York and must take care of New York and US federal income taxes.
This was some years ago. Maybe it's different now, maybe other schools feel differently.

Edit:
Given the wildly erroneous tax advice in the comments, I will add this quote:
https://ttlc.intuit.com/turbotax-support/en-us/help-article/income/remote-income-taxable-new-york-state/L5QWawxC5_US_en_US

Is my remote income taxable in New York State?
...
Your remote work is considered taxable if you’re doing it for yourself and not because your employer requires you to work remotely.
...
If you sometimes work remotely outside the state for your own reasons, yes, your income will be taxed.

When a New York resident works in New York remotely while visiting another U.S. state or another country, their New York income is still taxable.

Edit:
https://newcanadianlife.com/can-i-work-remotely-for-a-us-company-from-canada/

You don’t need a work permit to work remotely in the US while staying in Canada.


What you said they told you was "we don't care, but you'll be in NY on paper". That's what "I'm doing work in New York and must take care of New York and US federal income taxes." means in this context. Because had they been agreeing to do it legally - they wouldn't have said that, because it's not true from legal point of view.

@littleadv I took them to mean "We have no objection to you working in Canada, but you must ensure that you are complying with Canadian law."

@DJClayworth yes.

@DJClayworth the problem is that they wouldn't be complying with the Canadian law. If it's a short trip, that's one thing, but permanent employment in a foreign country is not a trivial matter

Re your edit, the question is not about New York (or US) residents. It's true that the NYS is taxing remote work pretty aggressively, but it's only for people who are NYS residents to begin with.
